# Erlang Keyfind not finding

Tags: erlang

I have following stucture:

```
[tupples, {timeline, [{PID, [stuff]}] }]
```

And i want to get list of stuff

```
parse_data(Data,Pid) ->
case lists:keyfind(timeline, 1, Data) of
    false -> [];
    [] -> [];
    {timeline, Timelines } ->
        io:fwrite("~62p | ~62p ~n", [Pid, Timelines]),
        case lists:keyfind(Pid, 1, Timelines) of
            false ->
                [we end up here];
            RawData -> RawData %% we want to be here
        end
end.
```

I have no Idea Why it goes to second false branch. And Pid does match.

Sample data:

```
<13608.329.0> | [{<13608.329.0>,
              [{{'$gen_call',
                    {<13608.847.0>,#Ref<13608.0.2.4361>},
                    get_color},
                #{'__struct__' => 'Elixir.EveryColor.GeneratorWorker.RangeSet',
                  cache => [3288336,3288337,3288338,3288339,
                   3288340,3288341,3288342,3288343],
                  range => #{'__struct__' => 'Elixir.Range',
                    first => 3288344,
                    last => 3321887}}},
               {{'$gen_call',
                    {<13608.847.0>,#Ref<13608.0.2.4175>},
                    get_color},
                #{'__struct__' => 'Elixir.EveryColor.GeneratorWorker.RangeSet',
                  cache => [3288335,3288336,3288337,3288338,
                   3288339,3288340,3288341,3288342,
                   3288343],
                  range => #{'__struct__' => 'Elixir.Range',
                    first => 3288344,
                    last => 3321887}}}]}]
```

https://github.com/Hajto/erlangpl/blob/master/apps/epl/src/epl_timeline_observer.erl#L67

Edit:

I did little cleanup:

```
parse_data(Data,Pid) ->
    ListOfProcessHistories = strip_to_timeline(Data),
    strip_to_raw_data(ListOfProcessHistories, Pid).

strip_to_timeline(Data) ->
    case lists:keyfind(timeline, 1, Data) of
        false -> [];
        [] -> [];
        {timeline, Timelines } -> Timelines
    end.

strip_to_raw_data(Data, Pid) ->
    io:fwrite("~62p | ~62p ~n", [Pid, Data]),
    [{Key, _}] = Data,
    io:fwrite("~p || ~p ~n",[Key, Pid]),
    io:fwrite("~p~n", [is_pid(Pid)]),
    io:fwrite("~p~n", [is_pid(Key)]),
    io:fwrite("~p~n",[Pid == Key]),
    case lists:keyfind(Pid, 1, Data) of
        false -> ["kurwa"];
        RawData -> RawData
    end.
```

And after execution:

```
<13610.708.0> | [{<13610.708.0>,[]}]
<13610.708.0> || <13610.708.0>
true
true
false
```

And I am mesmerized now O_o.

EDIT:

```
term_to_binary/1
```

Same manner as above

```
    <<131,103,100,0,14,116,101,115,116,64,49,50,55,46,48,46,48,46,49,0,0,2,196,0,0,
  0,0,2>> || <<131,103,100,0,14,116,101,115,116,64,49,50,55,46,48,46,48,46,49,
               0,0,2,196,0,0,0,0,0>>
```

Comment: Seems fine at a first glance. Something more subtle is going on there.

Comment: Yup. Thats why i posted exact data i am working on. To make it easier to reproduce.

Comment: I replicated the example with dummy data and it ends up where it is supposed to (http://ideone.com/i3ZpC1). Maybe something is going on with your data.

Comment: I just don't know. Can't find where the problem is.

Comment: Would be better if you provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) for reproduce error.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. That data comes from another node via RPC. Maybe it's not a PID, but something that looks like pid when printed out? Binary maybe?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm providing MCVe is extremely hard. This code is part of big system. It retrieves data from second Erlang node.

Comment: Could you try printing `term_to_binary(Pid)` and `term_to_binary(Key)` from your second example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pids have invisible part called creation:

http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-September/081178.html

In case of node restarts this invisible part can change and it is actually a good thing, because that might be completely other Pid now. It is problematic that they are shown as the same thing when printed.
To see that they are actually different, you can use `term_to_binary` and check last byte.

Creation is always 0 on local node and 1, 2 or 3 when it is a remote pid. When you send pids between nodes they are automatically translated, but if you for example store them as string and then build them back with `list_to_pid` creation will be 0 and the pids won't compare.